# How to get the host user home directory in WSL Bash

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to get the Windows "host" user home directory from within bash, so my theoretical environment variable (or program)

```
echo $WINHOME
```

would output something like

```
/mnt/c/Users/dualed
```

Would this be somehow possible?

When I search for it, I only find results for the opposite (finding the LXSS user path from the host)

I have a fallback-idea of extracting it from `$PATH`, as there are some predictable paths like those containing `AppData`, but I'd prefer to keep it simple, if possible.

Comment: No, just the usual Linux variables like `HOME`, `PWD`, `USER`, but they all refer to the Linux user, not the Windows "host" user.

Comment: Apparently a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971719/drvfs-location-of-userprofile

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With `wslpath` and [`wslvar`](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu):

```bsh
$ wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"
/mnt/c/Users/felipesantos
```

Comment: however, `wslvar` is not installed in WSL by default

Comment: It is installed by default in Ubuntu and Ubuntu 20.04 WSL. I can't say for the others.

Comment: @felipecassiors I think availability is dependent on the WSL / Windows version, not on the Guest OS version, `wslvar` is available on my Windows 10 2004 build.

Comment: `wslvar` is preinstalled in the Ubuntu distro, according to https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu#ubuntu.

I'm not sure about `wslpath`, though. It seems to be introduced in Windows 10 v1803: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/

Comment: Since Ubuntu 22.04 the package `wslu` which contains `wslvar` is **not** installed by default. What is worse: Its installation requires installing 61 packages occupying 177 MB of disk space. See the discussion I opened: [Limit dependencies of the wslu package in Ubuntu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu/discussions/235)

Comment: you can install it via `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends wslu` to get rid of most dependencies (maybe due to your discussion, idk)

Answer (score 9):

Fortunately since Windows 10 build 17063 (included in Windows 10 1803) there is a more straightforward way of sharing environment variables between Windows and WSL - `WSLENV`.

To make `%USERPROFILE%` accessible in WSL you list the variable name in the `WSLENV` variable. If you are not using `WSLENV` yet then just run the following command once in a `cmd.exe` session. The command `setx` permanently writes variables to the master environment in the Windows registry:

```
setx WSLENV USERPROFILE/up
```

This `WSLENV` setting will cause WSL to make `%USERPROFILE%` from Windows accessible as `$USERPROFILE` in WSL shell. The Windows directory path will be converted to the Unix format. If you do not want to convert the path, just omit the `p`:

```
setx WSLENV USERPROFILE/u
```

If you need to transfer multiple variables separate them by a colon. More details:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#share-environment-variables-between-windows-and-wsl
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/

---

I use the variable in my `cdw` function (cd to Windows path). I define it in `~/.bash_aliases` which is executed automatically in Ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/bash

cdw () {
        if test "$#" -eq 0 ; then
                cd "$USERPROFILE"
        elif test "$1" = - ; then
                cd "$1"
        else
                cd -- "$(wslpath "$@")"
        fi
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may launch `cmd.exe` from bash to get the host environment variables.
In the following, `win_userprofile` has your answer, and the other variables
are for completeness.

```
win_userprofile="$(cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%UserProfile%" 2>/dev/null)"

win_userprofile_drive="${win_userprofile%%:*}:"
userprofile_mount="$(findmnt --noheadings --first-only --output TARGET "$win_userprofile_drive")"

win_userprofile_dir="${win_userprofile#*:}"

userprofile="${userprofile_mount}${win_userprofile_dir//\\//}"
```

Sources : [Craig Loewen](https://twitter.com/craigaloewen/status/883361886820999169) at Microsoft and
[Michael Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494061/michael-hoffman).

Comment: Well to be precise `$win_userprofile` contains the windows path, `$userprofile` holds the answer to my question, but yes that is pretty much what I was looking for. Though I'd prefer the translation from Windows path to Unix path to be less involved

Comment: I just found https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1834#issuecomment-346443730 "Windows Insider Build 17046 contains new 'wslpath' functionality that supports path translations"

Comment: Excellent answer. I had got many of the elements of it together, but I had two problems. (1) Because I thought I might need it, I was testing in a root (`sudo -s`) shell, and `cmd.exe` wasn't in my path, so I was looking for a way to find its path; in the log-on shell this isn't necessary. (2) Although `cmd.exe /c echo %userprofile%` gives the path in Windows, I was struggling with complex `sed` filters on `mount` or `df` to map the `(DriveLetter):` to the Linux path; `findmnt` is a very neat solution. Thanks very much: I've learnt quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Since my writing of this question, `wslpath` has been added to (to my knowledge) all WSL/LXSS distributions. This program can translate windows paths to the corresponding mount point on the Linux subsystem, therefore the easiest solution would be now:

```bash
export WINHOME=$(wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%" 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\r'))
# echo $WINHOME prints something like /mnt/c/Users/dualed
```

`wslpath` documentation is still sparse:

```bash
$> man wslpath
# No manual entry for wslpath
# See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

$> wslpath --help
wslpath: unrecognized option: -
wslpath: Invalid argument
Usage:
    -a    force result to absolute path format
    -u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
    -w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
    -m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with '/' instead of '\'

EX: wslpath 'c:\users'
```

#### Notes

- Windows commands often add carriage-return to the output which is also not removed by `wslpath`, and so may end up in the Linux output, `tr -d '\r'` gets rid of that
- For some time now, `cmd.exe` will print a warning message to stderr that it was started from an invalid directory, the `2>/dev/null` part removes that

Currently I'm using a small helper to retrieve any windows environment variable

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# 'winenv'
cmd.exe /C "echo %$*%" 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\r'
```

And using it like this

```bash
WINHOME=$(wslpath "$(winenv USERPROFILE)")
```

Comment: `wslpath` isn't a tool. It is just a symbolic link (i.e. soft link `ln -s`) of `/init` file in `rootfs` folder.

Comment: Yes, it seems `/init` is the executable behind `wslpath`, but it acts differently when called as `wslpath`, so I would still call the tool `wslpath` and not `/init` and it was also announced as `wslpath` by the devs: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1834#issuecomment-346443730

Comment: `echo` appends carriage return https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433

Comment: This is why I use `| tr -d '\r'`, it removes the carriage return

Answer (score 3):

```
/mnt/c/Users/"$(wslvar USERNAME)"
```

[wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) - a collection of utilities for Windows 10 Linux Subsystem, such as retrieving Windows 10 environment variables or creating your favorite Linux GUI application shortcuts on Windows 10 Desktop.

Requires Windows 10 Creators Update; Some of the feature requires a higher version of Windows 10; Supports WSL2.

Comment: A user directory does not have to be on the `C:` drive, nor in the `Users` directory, nor in fact does the user home need to be in a directory named like the *username*. Drives being mounted in `/mnt/` is probably also distribution-specific... `wslu` seems like a good idea if you need support on older systems, but why didn't you just use `wslupath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"`?

Comment: Try to create a file for example: `touch wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"/test.txt`. As a result: `touch: cannot touch 'C:\Users\SOME_USERNAME/test.txt': No such file or directory`. Or like this: `touch /mnt/c/Users/"$(wslvar USERNAME)"/test.conf`. It works. Yes `/mnt` may be changed and user profile may not be on `C` drive. But a similar solution works for me and may be useful in some cases to others.

Comment: It does work with the correct syntax, you have to use a subshell in those cases: `touch $(wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"/test.txt)`

Answer (score 2):

```
wslpath "$(powershell.exe '$env:USERPROFILE')"
```

===

Above line of command will use `wslpath` to translate the Windows path to the WSL path, and the remain thing is all about how to get the Windows path of host user home in WSL, which we have many ways to get it.

`wslpath` command will do the thing which we want it to do by default, though you still can provide argument `-u` to clarify its behavior:

```
wslpath -u "$(powershell.exe '$env:USERPROFILE')"
```

I prefer the way which used PowerShell, it's just quite simple and clean, other alternatives are as following:

```
wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo | set /p _=%USERPROFILE%" 2>/dev/null)
wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%" 2>/dev/null)
```

Note: you should not use `wslvar` command for retrieving the path, this command not exists on some distros, like Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Code only answers are useless to future visitors.  Please edit it and provide an explanation for it.

Comment: Actually this is the best answer here. It's perfectly concise and directly answers the question.

Comment: Excellent answer, uses commands already invocable from WSL, and it's a one liner. I was hoping to avoid having to install `wslu` as many other answers required.

Answer (score 1):

This is my *reference answer*, should the question not be answerable at this time, or be unclear. It does what I wrote in the question I wanted to avoid - **guessing** the user's home directory by looking for fields containing `AppData` (and a bit more) within `$PATH`

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=':' read -a fields <<<"$PATH"

for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
        if [[ $field =~ ^(/mnt/.*)/AppData/Local/.* ]]; then
                echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                exit
        fi
done
```

It does require of course that there is at least one path in `%APPDATA%` in Windows, and (more problematic in my opinion) that there is no AppData path set with other user names, e.g. in global scope and finally that the home directory is actually mounted in `/mnt`.

Example output:

```
$ winhome
/mnt/c/Users/dualed
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of great info here! thanks. i needed an additional tweak..

when i use the `cmd.exe` trick in my `.bash_aliases` file, i get errors due to unwanted newline characters from CMD echo, which `wslpath` passes thru:

```
$ echo $(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%") | cat -A
C:\Users\myself^M$
               ^-- no good, wslpath turns into /mnt/c/Users/myself^M$
```

[CMD echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) does not seem to have anything like the `-n` option from [bash echo](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html), so borrowing from a StackOverflow post ([Windows batch: echo without newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336754/3029276)), i added a pseudo-chomp to remove them:

```
$ echo $(cmd.exe /C "echo | set /p _=%USERPROFILE%") | cat -A
C:\Users\myself
               ^-- all gone!
```

and now my alias is happy:

```
export WINHOME="$(wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo | set /p _=%USERPROFILE%"))"
```

Comment: Yes, good point, I remember running into that, then obviously forgot to update my answer -  though I removed the `\r` within WSL, I think I used something like  `| tr -d '\r'` (seeing as `\r` is not valid within windows paths anyway), but that's just me being more comfortable in Linux

Answer (score 1):

run `echo $env:UserName` as inline command using the `-Command` parameter of `powershell.exe` from a bash prompt.

```
steve@hpenvy11:~$ var1=$(powershell.exe -Command 'echo $env:UserName')
steve@hpenvy11:~$ echo $var1
steve
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know your Windows userid, you can put this in your .profile:
export WINHOME=$(wslpath C:/Users/dualed)

Comment: I **don't** want to hardcode the path, otherwise I could simply set the Unix path directly. Also `wslpath` only works in insider builds right now.

Comment: OK. add these two lines to .profile:

Comment: apps=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep WindowsApps); export WINHOME=${WINHOME%%/AppData*}

Comment: oops:     export WINHOME=${apps%%/AppData*}

Comment: The above will fail if there is more than one WindowsApps in $PATH. Best to just create a one-line shell script containing:     echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/\n/g'  |  grep WindowsApps | sed 's,/AppData.*,, | sort -u

Answer (score 0):

How about `sudo vi /etc/passwd` and change the HOME field (6th colon-separated field, initially set to `/home/wsluser`) to `/mnt/c/Users/winuser` (or wherever your `%USERPROFILE%` directory is mounted).  Then it is available as `$HOME` and everything works the way you're expecting it to!

Answer (score 0):

I use this [user input hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27773874) because `echo` in Windows appends carriage return:

```shell
echo "START $(wslpath $(cmd.exe /C '<nul set /p =%USERPROFILE%')) END"
START /mnt/c/Users/User12.name123 END
```

Compare with `echo` solution:

```shell
echo "START $(wslpath $(cmd.exe /C 'echo %USERPROFILE%')) END"
 ENDT /mnt/c/Users/User12.name123
```

[SET command documentation (ss64.com)](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
env | grep '\\Users\\<your-username>'
```

?

In Cygwin, I get

```
HOMEPATH=\Users\<my-username>
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\<my-username>
APPDATA=C:\Users\<my-username>\AppData\Roaming
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\<my-username>\AppData\Local
```

Of course Cygwin is not the same as WSL,
but there might be an easy answer that’s been under your nose all this time.

Comment: Users on WSL are completely independent from Windows users. When setting up a WSL environment you create a completely separate WSL-Only user. A person may choose any name valid in the chosen distribution, so that's not useful in my case as I was looking for a generic solution.

Comment: By default Windows variables are not transferred to WSL.

Answer (score -3):

in WSL2 all you need is:

`echo $PWD`