# How to get WSL to show the path /mnt/c/Users/$User on load like hyper.is and windows terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am open to a different approach if what I want to do is not recommended. When I open up ubuntu bash from wsl on windows. I am in the path `/home/linuxUserName` now when I use a different terminal like hyper.is configured to use wsl base.exe or windows terminal (preview) both drop me into on load in the path `/mnt/c/Users/windowsUserName` This is what I prefer because then I can run my npm and node commands along with bash commands in the windows directory where my project lives at `/mnt/c/Users/windowsUserName/sites` (or the equivalent windows path)

The main reason I am wanting this in plain ubuntu bash is because I have a friends computer who wouldn't install hyper, and not sure if windows terminal will work, haven't tried yet.

Normally in linux I thought you would just export your path in bashrc I tried this

```
export PATH=/mnt/c/Users/windowsUserName:$PATH
```

I tried something from here [How to get the host user home directory in WSL Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1271205/how-to-get-the-host-user-home-directory-in-wsl-bash) exporting my path but that did not work

```
export WINHOME=$(wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%"))
```

Ok hope someone can help. Why does hyper.is and windows terminal have this work out of the box, but it's hard in ubuntu bash native terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Just add `cd /mnt/c/Users/YourWinUserName` in `.bashrc` file or what the rc file of default shell.

Comment: I added that to the bottom of the .bashrc file and reloaded ubuntu bash, still in the same directory. I didn't see any other bash files like bash_profile

Comment: Why not share your windows user path with linux?  Move anything from the linux home folder into /mnt/c/Users/windowsUserName.  Delete your old linux home and ln -s /mnt/c/Users/windowsUserName /home/linuxUserName.  The only problem I have had with this is some linux apps don't like that file permissions are always open.