# Bash alias to change to host user home folder in WSL2

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

refferencing [How to get the host user home directory in WSL Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1271205/how-to-get-the-host-user-home-directory-in-wsl-bash)

(I don't have reputation yet to add a comment)

the great answer from @felipecassiors:
`wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)"`

I am trying to turn this into an alias command and my UserProfile has a space so it causes issues:

`alias winhome='cd $(wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)")'`

When I run 'winhome':

`# -bash: cd: too many arguments`

I've tried several ways to add quotes or escape the space - to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

okay.  it became obvious once I hit the nail on the head:

`alias winhome='cd "$(wslpath "$(wslvar USERPROFILE)")"'`

Comment: Yes. Each `$()` has its own quoting context, so quotes inside don't mix with quotes outside. Double quoting `$()` [is the right thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).